# Why does Rust promote use statements with explicit imports?

Tags: rust

I see a lot of Rust code where the `use` statements look like this:

```
use std::io::net::ip::{SocketAddr, Ipv4Addr};
```

The way I get it, this restricts the `use` statement to only import `SocketAddr` and `Ipv4Addr`.

Looking from the perspective of languages such as Java or C# this feels odd as with such languages an import statement always imports all public types.

I figured one can have the same in Rust using this statement.

```
use std::io::net::ip::*;
```

The only reason I could see for the explicit naming would be to avoid conflicts where two different imports would contain public APIs with the same names. However, this could be worked around with aliasing so I wonder if there's another advantage of the more strict "import only what is needed" approach?

Comment: One other way to do things is you can `use std::io::net::ip`. Then in your code access types with `ip::SocketAddr`. You don't risk any namespace collisions with the glob import while retaining short types.

Comment: I think you mean "import" everywhere you write "export", or I didn't understand your point. Edit: Also in Java you have `import com.acme.dynamite.Stick` as well as `import com.acme.dynamite.*`, it's just that the preference is switched.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My wording was incorrect in the initial question.

Comment: @delnan `*` imports are frowned upon in Java land as well (unless you import more than 10'ish types from a package), the preference is not switched.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust is in this inspired by Python, which has a similar principle: importing is all explicit, and though glob imports (`use x::*` in Rust, `from x import *` in Python) are supported, they are not generally recommended.

This philosophy does have some practical impacts; calling a trait method, for example, can only be done if the trait is in scope, and so calling a trait method when there are name collisions in the imported traits is rather difficult (this will be improved in the future with Uniform Function Call Syntax, where you can call `Trait::function(self)` rather than just `self.function()`).

Mostly, though, it is something that is well expressed in the Zen of Python: "explicit is better than implicit". When vast swathes of things are in scope, it can be difficult to see what came from where, and intimate knowledge of the module structure, and/or tooling becomes quite important; if it is all explicit, tooling is largely unnecessary and working with files by hand in a simple text editor is entire feasible. Sure, tooling will still be able to assist, but it is not as *necessary*.

This is why Rust has adopted Python's explicit importing philosophy.

Answer (score 6):

- [Mailing list thread asking why glob imports are not preferred](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2014-March/thread.html#8981)

in which Huon writes

> Certain aspects of them dramatically complicate the name resolution 
>   algorithm (as I understand it), and, anyway, they have various downsides 
>   for the actual code, e.g. the equivalent in Python is frowned upon: 
>   http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#importing
>
> Maybe they aren't so bad in a compiled & statically typed language? I 
>   don't know; either way, I personally find code without glob imports 
>   easier to read, because I can work out which function is being called 
>   very easily, whereas glob imports require more effort.

- [Issue to remove glob imports](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/11825)

where nikomatsakis writes

> I think glob imports have their place. For example, in the borrow
>   checker, there is a shallow tree of submodules that all make use of
>   data types defined in `borrowck/mod.rs`. It seems rather tedious and
>   silly to require manual importing of all these names, vs just writing
>   `use rustc::middle::borrowck::*`. I know that there are complications
>   in the resolution algorithm, though, and I would be more amenable to
>   an argument based on fundamental challenges there.

This then moved to [RFC 305](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/305) which was rejected by steveklabnik without comment on whether they're good style:

> Glob imports are now stable, and so I'm going to give this a close.

Comment: References are great, but link-only answers are thrown upon. Your answer will be worthless as soon as those urls are dead. If you wish to improve your answer, then write the meat of it right here (you can quote) and only use the links to back-up the answer and provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

Global import is a convenience for developers during development stage, import everything all at once because at this stage importing each items one by one may be cumbersome. They are exported under `prelude` module specifically designed for this purpose.

Once you finished your logic, replace glob imports with explicit ones because glob imports are hard to trace, requires extra effort to find what comes from where.

They are referred as wildcard imports in Rust.

They are frowned upon because:

- can pollute the namespace
- can cause clashes and lead to confusing errors
- macro related issues around tooling

I don't think it has anything to do with Python.

Arguments for their deprecation has strong merits but deprecating wildcard imports may not be feasible and can impacts developer productivity but one can set clippy lints.

`warn-on-all-wildcard-imports`: bool: Whether to allow certain wildcard imports (prelude, super in tests). (defaults to false).

Read more https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#wildcard_imports

Answer (score 0):

Requiring explicit imports enables code readers to see quickly and precisely which thing a local symbol corresponds to. This often helps them to navigate directly to that code.

```
use somelib:*;
use otherlib:*;

// Where does SomeType come from? Good luck finding it in a large
// project if you're new.
fn is_brassy(input: SomeType) {
  return input.has_brass;
}
```

Also, wildcard imports can hide undeclared dependencies. If some code doesn't declare its dependencies, but it is always imported along with its dependencies in a wildcard import, the code will run fine. But readers looking at that code file in isolation may be confused about where the symbol comes from.

(The following code tries to demonstrate the issue in Python-like pseudo-code because I’m more proficient in expressing my thoughts using Python, even though the actual time I’ve seen this was with Rust macros.)

```
# helpers
def helpful_helper(x):
  return x + ' world'
```

```
# helpless
def needs_help(x):
  # helpful_helper not explicitly imported!
  return helpful_helper(x)
```

```
# lib
from helpers import *
from helpless import *
```

```
# app
from lib import *

needs_help('hello')
```

A different dependency might even be used if different imports were used together.

```
# other_app
from other_helpers import *
from helpless import *

# what does it do? Better look at other_helpers.py...
needs_help('hello')
```